# How to show title position on top of the text

Tags: angular

I need to show title position on top of the text.
app.component.html

```
<td  ><span title="{{item.info}}" style="cursor: pointer;"  > {{item.ref}}</span></td>
```

Thank you

Answer (score 2):

u can use [MatTooltip](https://material.angular.io/components/tooltip/overview) he have position where need to render tooltip(if it possible)

Answer (score 1):

You can use [this](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-tooltip) package for tooltip you can design your own tooltip with custom positions.